# how do i get it to ask again if year level put in is out of max and min

Tags: python, try-catch, minimax

```
year = int(input("what year are you in?"))     

while (year) <MIN_YEAR or (year) > MAX_YEAR or not year.isalpha():
    print("Thats not within Carmels Year levels please try again


    year = int(input("what year are you     in?"))
```

Comment: The range check is fine. You've already converted `years` to an `int` (or at least, you have if `int(...)` doesn't raise an exception), so `year.isalpha` is both an error and unnecessary.

Comment: The standard idiom is to use a `while True:` loop with the call to `input` as the first line of the body, followed by an `if` statement to use `break` if the input is valid. This avoids having to duplicate the call to `input` prior to the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
year = input("what year are you in?")
min_year, max_year = 2009, 2020
while not (year.isdigit() and min_year < int(year) < max_year):
    year = input("That's not within Carmels Year levels please try again:")
else:
    year = int(year)

print(year)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is mostly correct: you just have an extraneous and erroneous attempt to call `year.isalpha` (`year` is already an `int` at this point, not a `str`):

```
year = int(input("what year are you in?"))     

while (year) <MIN_YEAR or (year) > MAX_YEAR:
    print("Thats not within Carmels Year levels please try again")
    year = int(input("what year are you     in?"))
```

Switch to an infinite loop with a `break` statement to avoid duplicating the call to `input`.

```
while True:
    year = int(input("What year are you in?"))
    if MIN_YEAR <= year <= MAX_YEAR:
        break
    print("Thats not within Carmels Year levels please try again")
```

Now that we only have one call to `input` and `int`, we can add some additional error checking more easily. If you are going to call `int` anyway, let it check if the input is numeric as part of its normal functioning.

```
while True:
    year = input("What year are you in?")
    try:
        year = int(year)
    except ValueError:
        print("Not a valid year")
        continue

    if MIN_YEAR <= year <= MAX_YEAR:
        break
    print("Thats not within Carmels Year levels please try again")
```

Answer (score 0):

You might do something similar to the following code snippet.

```
MIN_YEAR = 1900
MAX_YEAR = 2525

def get_year():
    year = 1900
    
    while True:
        yr = input('What year are you in: ')
    
        if not yr.isnumeric():
            print('Please only enter numbers')
            continue
            
        if int(yr) < MIN_YEAR or int(yr) > MAX_YEAR:
            print('Entry must be in the range of ', MIN_YEAR, ' to ', MAX_YEAR)
            continue
            
        break
        
    return yr
    
year = get_year()

print('Entered year is :', year)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a while True loop instead, and use the break keyword to exit the loop

```
while True:
    year = int(input("what year are you in?"))
    min = 2000
    max = 2010
    while not (min < year < max_year):
        print("That's not within Carmels Year levels please try again:")
    else:
       break
```